# Can't pass user location to Polymer iron-ajax call to get venues from Foursquare

Tags: polymer

I am making an application with Polymer, Google Maps and Foursquare API, but I'm stuck. The idea is to show the user's nearby venues, which are returned form Foursquare. I am using `<iron-ajax>` to get the venues from Foursquare.

I've made a custom element, and I'm using `geolocation` to get the user's location, and trying to pass it to `<iron-ajax>`. The AJAX call works perfectly when I pass latitude and longitude manually, but when I try to change values to `geolocation` values, the AJAX call breaks.

**Template:**

```
<template>
  <geo-location watch-pos latitude="{{ latitude }}" longitude="{{ longitude }}"></geo-location>
  <google-map latitude="[[latitude]]" longitude="[[longitude]]" zoom="13" api-key="AIzaSyCZ52mvUoJplSOmOFE2KW0u5v6jny870IM">
  <!--  <google-map-marker latitude="[[latitude]]" longitude="[[longitude]]" draggable="true"></google-map-marker>-->
  </google-map>

  <iron-ajax
    auto
    url="https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?"
    params="{{ajaxParams}}"
    last-response="{{data}}"
    handle-as="json"
    >
    </iron-ajax>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data.response.venues]]">
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>

  </template>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'my-list',

  properties: {
        client_id: {
            type: String,
            value: 'THIS IS MY CLIENT_ID'
        },
        client_secret: {
            type: String,
            value: 'THIS IS MY CLIENT_SECRET'
        },
        v: {
            type: Number,
            value: '20150729'
        },
        limit: {
            type: Number,
            value: '10'
        },
        ll: {
            type: String,
            value:
              getCurrentLat(function(pos){
                console.log(pos);
              })
        },
        ajaxParams: {
            type: String,
            computed: 'processParams(client_id, client_secret, v, limit, ll)'
        }
    },

    processParams: function(client_id, client_secret, v, limit, ll) {
        return {
        client_id: client_id,
        client_secret: client_secret,
        v: v,
        limit:limit,
        ll: ll
      };
    }
});

function getCurrentLat(callback) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        callback(position.coords.latitude + ", " + position.coords.longitude);
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Unable to access your geolocation");
  }
}
```

**And this is the part where location information should be added:**

```
ll: {
    type: String,
    value:
         getCurrentLat(function(pos){
            console.log(pos);
         })
},
```

Whenever I set the `ll` value to `'60, 25'` for example, the AJAX call returns the right things. Also, this `console.log` above prints the user's location correctly (something like `60, 24`), but I don't know how to set `pos` to be the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `ll` property declaration has an invalid `value` field, which is meant to provide an initial value. It is not intended to setup callbacks like you're attempting to do. You should probably leave that field blank initially:

```
Polymer({
  ...
  properties: {
    ll: String
  }
});
```

The value of `ll` can be set imperatively in JavaScript (i.e., `this.ll = position;`) or declaratively in your markup with a data binding (i.e., `<my-element ll="[[position]]">`). Since the `ll` value needs to come asynchronously from `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`, we can invoke it from your Polymer element's lifecycle callback (e.g., `attached`), and then imperatively set `ll` in the `geolocation` callback:

```
Polymer({
  ...
  attached: function() {
    getCurrentLat(function(position) {
      this.ll = position;
    }.bind(this));
  }
});
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/qRRjJX?editors=1010)

But it looks like you're also using the [`<geo-location>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/ebidel/geo-location) element, which already reads the current latitude/longitude for you and provides real-time updates, so you don't really need to use `navigator.geolocation` yourself (which is a one-time update in your case).

Instead of the change above, you could modify the `ajaxParams` computed property to be based on the already existing `latitude` and `longitude` properties (populated by `<geo-location>`):

```
Polymer({
  ...
  properties: {
    ajaxParams: {
      type: String,
      computed: 'processParams(client_id, client_secret, v, limit, latitude, longitude)'
    }
  },

  processParams: function(client_id, client_secret, v, limit, latitude, longitude) {
    return {
      client_id: client_id,
      client_secret: client_secret,
      v: v,
      limit:limit,
      ll: latitude + ", " + longitude
    };
  }
});
```

That would also allow you to get rid of `getCurrentLat()`.

Note that the Geolocation API is [only available from secure origins](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only), as of Chrome 50. You'll notice a console warning if you try to use it from `http` instead of `https`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried both ways you suggested, but it's still not working.. I think that better way is to use `<geo-location>`, but when I tried it, `latitude` and `longitude` were both `null`. I don't know how to get those values from `<geo-location>` to the `ajaxParams`.

Comment: The codepen I included works for me, so the problem must be something specific to your environment or the way you're testing it. Are you testing this on https? And did you click "Allow" when prompted for geolocation permission?

Comment: Geolocation is allowed, and I'm not testing this on https. I really don't know what the problem is. This is the reason why I tried this without using `<geo-location>`. Though I didn't get it to work with `getCurrentLat()` either

Comment: The Geolocation API is only available from https (you should see a notice in the console that states this, as seen in updated answer).

Comment: It's working! I feel so stupid now.. I didn't notice to add `HTMLImports()` before `Polymer()`.... Thank you so much! Now I get the venues nearby my location.